# Doctrine MYSQL 150+ tables: generating models works, but not vice-versa?

Tags: php, code-generation, doctrine

I can generate my models and schema.yml file based on an existing database. But when I try to do it the other way around using `Doctrine::createTablesFromModels()` i get an error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064

So either of these works:

```
    Doctrine::generateYamlFromDb(APPPATH . 'models/yaml');
    Doctrine::generateYamlFromModels(APPPATH . 'models/yaml', APPPATH . 'models');
    Doctrine::generateModelsFromYaml(APPPATH . 'models/yaml', APPPATH . 'models', array('generateTableClasses' => true));
    Doctrine::generateModelsFromDb(APPATH . 'models', array('default'), array('generateTableClasses' => true));
```

But this fails (it drops/creates the database and around 50 tables):

```
    Doctrine::dropDatabases();
    Doctrine::createDatabases();
    Doctrine::createTablesFromModels();
```

The partially outputted SQL query shows that the error is around the `Notification` object which looks like this:

**Any leads would be highly appreciated!**

```
<?php
// Connection Component Binding
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->bindComponent('Notification', 'default');

/**
 * BaseNotification
 * 
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 * 
 * @property integer $n_auto_key
 * @property integer $type
 * @property string $title
 * @property string $message
 * @property timestamp $entry_date
 * @property timestamp $update_date
 * @property integer $u_auto_key
 * @property integer $c_auto_key
 * @property integer $ub_auto_key
 * @property integer $o_auto_key
 * @property integer $notified
 * @property integer $read
 * @property integer $urgence
 * 
 * @package    ##PACKAGE##
 * @subpackage ##SUBPACKAGE##
 * @author     ##NAME## <##EMAIL##>
 * @version    SVN: $Id: Builder.php 6820 2009-11-30 17:27:49Z jwage $
 */
abstract class BaseNotification extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('Notification');
        $this->hasColumn('n_auto_key', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('type', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '1',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('title', 'string', 50, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '50',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('message', 'string', null, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('entry_date', 'timestamp', 25, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '25',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('update_date', 'timestamp', 25, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '25',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('u_auto_key', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('c_auto_key', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('ub_auto_key', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('o_auto_key', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '4',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('notified', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'default' => '0',
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '1',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('read', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'default' => '0',
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '1',
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('urgence', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'default' => '0',
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => '1',
             ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using reserved words as column names (later on also as table names) and the 'quoting' option for Doctrine didn't seem to be turned on automatically....